# HTML no Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Existe algum atalho/técnica para colocar `<p>` e `</p>` em uma linha do Visual Studio Code?

*Assim como `Ctrl`+ ; transforma a linha em um comentário*

Comment: Crie um [snippet/atalho](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) para executar a escrita dessa tag.

Answer (score 2):

É só apertar `p + tab`, isso é padrão do VS Code, a não ser que vc tenha instalado alguma extensão que mudou esse comportamento default do software.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, vc quer usar um comando que a cada linha ele insira uma abertura de tag ao início do parágrafo e o fechamento de tag ao final. Eu desconheço.

Mas imaginando que você tenha um texto enorme com vários parágrafos.
Você pode fazer manualmente é, colocar cada parágrafo em uma linha, imaginando que você tenha um (*) asterisco ao início de cada linha e um .(ponto final) ao fim do parágrafo.

Exemplo:

- Parágrafo 1.
- Parágrafo 2.
- Parágrafo 3.

Tu seleciona o asterisco ou o ponto final e pressionar ctrl + D até selecionar todos (nesse caso vc tem um padrão) assim você substitui asterisco por `<p>` e o ponto final por `</p>`